# Is there a better way to improve the complexity of a algorithm that includes multiple arrays in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance

I am working on a project that is using the google cloud speech-to-text api. The result from the api returns an object that has multiple arrays of transcript and each array contains an array for each word and their properties, which is an object. I want to filter through every words in the transcript, and see if it matches another array of words I want to filter out.

Here's a simplified example if it sounds confusing.

```
resultFromApi = {
   results:[
      [{word:"hello", startTime:"00:00:00",endTime:"00:00:02"},...],
      [{word:"world", startTime:"00:00:02",endTime:"00:00:04"},...]
   ]
}
wordsToFilter = ["hello", "there", "this", "is", "a", "test"]
```

My question is, is there a faster way other than something like this?

```
resultFromApi.results.forEach((result) => {
   result.forEach((e) => {
      if(wordsToFilter.includes(e.word)){
         ...
      }
   })
});
```

Edit: Syntax problem

Comment: Yes, I edited it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the minimum, one thing you can do to improve the computational complexity of the code would be to change the `wordsToFilter` array to a Set. The complexity of `Array.prototype.includes` is `O(n)`, but the complexity of `Set.prototype.has` is `O(1)`. So if

```
if(wordsToFilter.includes(e.word)){
```

is your current code, and it works for you, you can change the code to

```
const wordsToFilter = new Set(["hello", "there", "this", "is", "a", "test"]);
// ...
if(wordsToFilter.has(e.word)){
```

to decrease the computational complexity by a factor of `n`, from `O(n^3)` overall to `O(n^2)`.

You have an array of arrays of objects, and you need to iterate over all objects, so you *have* to use a nested loop to iterate, which is `O(n ^ 2)`, so after that, there's no way to fundamentally improve the computational complexity.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will take a look into Set, and how it achieves O(1) when searching.